# How to display value in multiple textviews using GET method in android?

Tags: java, android

**What I am trying to do is, fetch the datas from server using GET method and display them in multiple textfields.
I have already made model class, interface and created constructor, but still the app throws onFailure message.**

```
TextView name;

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

String url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    name = view.findViewById(R.id.proName);
    name.setText("");


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    PlaceHolderApi placeHolderApi = retrofit.create(PlaceHolderApi.class);

    Call<List<profileDetails>> call = placeHolderApi.getDetails();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<profileDetails>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<profileDetails>> call, Response<List<profileDetails>> response) {
            List<profileDetails> data=response.body();

            **for (int i=0; i<data.size();i++)
                name.append("Aa"+ data.get(i).getTitle());**

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<profileDetails>> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"nah it",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Could you check what causes `onFailure`?

Comment: Change `Toast` on `onFailure` to this `Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error Cause : "+t,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. This should be show what error when you call an API. Or using `Log` instead to make it easier to copy the error.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting is a json object so try to create a model class having a data member of type List and making a call of type List make a call of that model type. This may resolve your issue.